# Crafting a C# RegEx Match returns unexpected data

Tags: c#, regex

```
String:  (0/0/26)*15
MyRegEx: (?<!\*)\d+
```

I'm trying to match all digits except when preceded by a * (eg: 0, 0, 26)
When I use my regex with a backwards qualifier its matching 0, 0, 26, and 5.

Where am I messing up?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `'5'` in `'15'` does not have a `'*'` before it.

Wrap [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) around your `\d+` pattern:

```
(?<!\*)\b\d+\b
```

to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You are matching one or more digit in front of which there is no '*'. That's why you match 5 (and not 15).

Change to:

```
(?<![\*\d])\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

5 is a character, that is not behind a * so it is matched

long version:

your pattern searches for digit-characters, that are not behind a *

you have to change your pattern